# Optional condition not working linq

Tags: c#, linq

I having some problem in Optional condition in Lambda express like

```
var shouldCheckDate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(fromDate);
var result = (from r in db.Notify
              where r.ApplicationId == applicationId
              && (shouldCheckDate || r.CreatedDate.Date > date)
              select r
              ).Count;
```

problem is here it always excuting both condition either `shouldCheckDate` true are false. I am doing any thing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "executing both conditions"? You mean it always returns items with `r.CreatedDate.Date > date`?

Comment: Show the error message. I doubt that .Date is supported by your provider.

Comment: put && instead of || condition and check

Comment: @Evk yes its true

Comment: `shouldCheckDate` is poorly named (it seem to represent the opposite), but other than that it looks ok (as soon as `Date` property is supported by the provider)

Comment: But now the query becomes wrong. The `where` condition should be `(!shouldCheckDate || r.CreatedData.Date > date)`. I assume `date` is `DateTime` variable parsed from `fromDate` when `shouldCheckDate` is `true`. So the query would either ignore the `r.CreatedData.Date > date` condition or apply it depending on `shouldCheckDate` variable. Of course yo could get rid of all that by using LINQ method syntax and conditional `Where` chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compose the IQueryable by adding the where clauses only when needed:

```
var query = db.Notify;
query = query.Where(r => r.ApplicationId == applicationId);
if (shouldCheckDate) {
    query = query.Where(r => r.CreatedDate.Date > date);
}
var result = query.Count();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the fact, that LINQ is translated to SQL and SQL, in contrast to C#, executes all parts of a condition, no matter if one of them allready returned true.

Answer (score 0):

You have OR statement here,

```
(shouldCheckDate || r.CreatedDate.Date > date)
```

so even one of these conditions which is `true` is enough for whole statement to be true.

Maybe `r.CreatedDate.Date` is always `> date` ?